# Learning German through debates/ discussions - Deutsch lernen durch Debatten/ Reden

Tags: learning, writing

Ich habe mir gedacht dass man ab einem gewissen Deutschniveau auch durch Schreiben Fortschritte machen kann.

Habt ihr Blogs, oder kennt ihr eine Seite wo man an Debatten teilnehmen kann?

Ich habe zum Beispiel einen Blog gestartet, aber es gelang mir nicht mich derart bei einer Gesellschaft Deutschlerner anzuschließen.

Also, kennt ihr Plätze, wo man debattieren kann?
Oder hat jemand von euch Lust auf Debatten?

Comment: Ja, [diese hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: lol, ok, ich werde sie probieren :P

Comment: Komisch, die meisten Menschen mit funktionalem Selbsterhaltungstrieb versuchen, Debatten im Internet aus dem Weg zu gehen ;)

Comment: es ist kein Problem weniger intelligente Themen zu diskutieren.... Das Problem ist wo ich Leute finden kann :P

Comment: Die Frage ist, ob Du dort Korrektoren findest, denn es gilt allgemein als unhöflich.

Answer (score 4):

Wir haben hier schon so etwas, nämlich unseren:

- [German Language Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language)

Dort kann jeder, der die Mindestreputation von 20 Punkten erreicht hat, nach Lust und Laune auf Deutsch oder auf Englisch debattieren und diskutieren. Man muss sich nur treffen. Es gibt kein festes Thema und keine *"off topic"* Diskussionen, außer dass es im weitesten Sinne um das Üben und Erlernen der deutschen Sprache gehen soll. Die [allgemeinen Chatregeln](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) sollten aber schon eingehalten werden.

Ab 100 Reputation kannst Du sogar einen eigenen Chatroom gründen, wenn Du ein bestimmtes Thema diskutieren willst, das nicht von allgemeinem Interesse ist, oder wenn Du mit einem bestimmten User eine Diskussion haben möchtest.

Leider ist der Chat in letzter Zeit etwas zu ruhig geworden, aber das geht hoffentlich bald vorbei.